# Display Status Only to group members in P2 theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've just started to work with WordPress and trying to create a Micro-Blogging Site like twitter. I've installed P2 theme. It's working fine.we can post our statuses like tweets and all.

Now the problem where I am stuck is that:-

As soon as any user logs into the site( I am running it on my localhost and had created users on my own from backend) he/she can see all the posts and tweets of all other users.

So I tried to make few groups and assign several users to each of the groups.
Since I am totally new to WP I searched for may plugins which can allow me to create group and assign members , So that the user from a particular group can see the posts and tweets of the users of that same group.

But I am unable to find out any such plugin(or it might be that I am unable to use the plugins which I found through googling around).

So please can anyone help me to get around this problem.

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks,
chirag.tyagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://wpmu.org/how-to-build-a-mini-twitter-site-with-buddypress-your-open-source-microblogging-platform/) had a Buddypress theme that integrated with P2 so that you could use BP's group functionality with P2 but it seems to be down and the other mirrors to this project are also down.

However there are workarounds that couple BP's Groups functionality with plugins to clone Twitter with hashtags and followers and the private groups you desire. See [this](http://wpmu.org/how-to-build-a-mini-twitter-site-with-buddypress-your-open-source-microblogging-platform/) for an example which I think should work for you.

Remember NOT to disable groups, contrary to what the post suggests.

Comment: Thanks Srijan , your answer  really proved to be useful for me. Now I am using Buddy Press and it is providing me all the functionalities which I needed. But still I would like to ask one more thing:- Like suppose when any user logs in to the site, the post which appears on his home page are the posts/updates/status from all the users of the site..In what dircetion should I proceed so   as to make sure that only the updates from the friend's or from the user which the logged in user is following , appears on the home page and not the whole of the updates... thanks in advance .

Comment: Try using the 'groups' functionality in BuddyPress. It limits the activity feed to a particular group. Make sure the said groups are private/hidden for this to function.
More info [here.](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/group-settings-and-roles/)

Comment: I guess I could not make you get my point, well I want to display the user related feeds only when the user logs in... I mean when ever a user enters in a group he is provided with all the feeds related to that group only... in the same way i want to limit the feeds on the home page as well.i.e feeds only from his friends should appear in the home page... a better example is like when we log into our facebook a/c we just see the posts only of our friends,or the group which we have joined...we are not displayed the post of any other fb user  which is not in our friends list...

Comment: Oh I now understand. Well there is not plugin to do this but just a bit of code will get it done for you. BP has a function for checking if someone is your friend. You can add this code in the cod for the activity stream and limit your view form non-friends or followers or members of your group as you desire.
Look [here.](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/custom-buddypress-loops/the-activity-stream-loop/) Remember to limit the scope to 'group' as mentioned in the possible arguments. The document has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks Srijan, you really helped me finishing this work.. Thanks a lot  ...Cheers...